# MinGW make shows "no target specified and no makefile found" error

Tags: windows, opencv, makefile, command

I'm on my windows 7 command prompt.

I'm trying to build openCV using some extra modules provided on someone's github.

The instructions say

```
 $ cd <opencv_build_directory>
 $ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>
 $ make -j5
```

The first two are finally done after installing cmake, and I just need to get the last command working.

I didn't have make, so I installed MinGW. 
When I set the path on cmd for a make executable that I found in the MinGW, it says "no target specified and no makefile found".

In C:\MinGW\bin I have a mingw32-make.exe file.
in C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin I have a make.exe file and also a makeinfo.exe file.

I've set the path to the location of both files, but they all return the error.

A makefile file is nowhere to be found in those folders. There are several Makefile files, but in different folders. I am unsure if they should be moved to a certain folder.

There is one in the vim folder and a Makefile.in and Makefile.am in the share\libtool folder.

How do I get the make working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick a makefile generator with the `-G` option.  Without that it will choose a default which is probably not Makefiles on a Windows system.  Run `cmake -G` and it will show all the generators available to you.

Probably you want something like `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ...`